# Proving that the pseudo inverse of a matrix is$ \mathbf{B}^\dagger = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t}\mathbf{B}^Tdt $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential, pseudoinverse

I have an exercise that I can't seem to spit out.
I want to use $$ \mathbf{I} - \int_0^\infty \mathbf{A} e^{-\mathbf{A}t}dt = \mathbf{0},\quad \forall\mathbf{A} \succ 0 $$ to prove that $$ \mathbf{B}^\dagger = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t}\mathbf{B}^Tdt $$ where B is a full column rank matrix $\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

This is what I got:
Let $\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B} = A$ since $\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}$ is positive definite by definition. Then using the first equation $$ \mathbf{I} - \int_0^\infty \mathbf{A} e^{-\mathbf{A}t}dt = \mathbf{0} $$
$$ \implies \mathbf{I} - \int_0^\infty \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B} e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t}dt = \mathbf{0} $$
$$ \implies \mathbf{I} =  \int_0^\infty \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B} e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t}dt$$
$$ \implies \mathbf{B}^{\dagger}B =  \int_0^\infty \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B} e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t}dt$$ since A is full column rank
I didn't know where to go from here since I don't know if I can pull out a B from the integral and if so, which side it should go.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Since $B^T B$ commutes with its own matrix exponential, you've effectively shown that $$\mathbf{I} =\int_0^\infty  e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t} \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B} dt=\left(\int_0^\infty  e^{-\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}t} \mathbf{B}^T dt\right)\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}^\dagger \mathbf{B}.$$ That is, you've shown that $B^\dagger$ is a left inverse of $B$. What remains is to show that this suffices to make $B^\dagger$ the pseudo-inverse.

Comment: A pseudo inverse of a matrix $A$ is any matrix $X$ such that $AXA=A$. There are several types of pseudo inverses. The Moore Penrose pseudo inverse $A^\dagger$ satisfies also the properties $A^\dagger A A^\dagger = A^\dagger$, $(AA^\dagger)^*=AA^\dagger$ and $(A^\dagger A)^*=A^\dagger A$. Is that what you meant by *pseudoinverse* in your OP?

Comment: @OliverDiaz yes by pseudo inverse I meant The Moore Penrose one

Comment: @J.Cricks. That is what I thought. In that case, as Semiclassical indicated, $B^\dagger$ is actually a left inverse of $B$ an account of $B^\intercal B$ being an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix, for then $B^\intercal B$ is diagonalizable and eigenvalues are strictly positive.